Setting ComboBox.DataSource to DataTable does not work with SQLite, although it should
I am writing a VB.NET WindowsForms application and I want to fill a ComboBox control from an SQLite database table by setting its DataSource property. This is supposed to work:
Fastest way of filling a combobox from a datatable in VB.Net
But when I run my code I get ComboBox populated with empty strings:
Dim sqliteCon As New SQLiteConnection
sqliteCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + dbFileName
sqliteCon.Open()
Dim sqliteCmd As SQLiteCommand = sqliteCon.CreateCommand()
Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader
'-----------------------------------
sqliteCmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS colorsT (colorID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Color TEXT);"
sqliteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
'-----------------------------------
sqliteCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO colorsT (Color) VALUES ('Red'), ('Green'), ('Blue');"
sqliteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
'-----------------------------------
sqliteCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Color FROM colorsT ORDER BY Color;"
reader = sqliteCmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim dT As New DataTable
dT.Load(reader)

ComboBox1.DataSource = dT
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Color"

Log(ComboBox1.Items(1).ToString) 'outputs: System.Data.DataRowView 

dT.Dispose()
reader.Close()
sqliteCmd.Dispose()
sqliteCon.Close()

I still can populate ComboBox with correct values by using a loop:
For Each row As DataRow In dT.Rows
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(row(0).ToString)
Next

But I think that is a less efficient approach.
What could possibly be the problem here?

Why are you disposing of the source of data (dT.Dispose())? The underlying DataManager wires up the Disposed event of the data source (when available, in this case it is), and releases the bindings when the event is raised. Also sets the DisplayMember to null (BTW, you should set the DisplayMember before the DataSource)

@Jimi BTW, you should set the DisplayMember before the DataSource - Alas, setting the DisplayMember before the DataSource makes no difference at all.

@Jimi Thank you for the hint! I don't understand why (since it is disposed anyway) but after I removed dT.Dispose(), the code worked! Problem solved!

You should set the DisplayMember before the DataSource because, if you do that after, the source of data is unmounted, then remounted to apply the changes caused by a new DisplayMember, so you affectively mount the data source twice. If the content of the source is not large, and it's not mounted frequently, you won't notice. Otherwise, you'll notice (and it's not exactly a subtle change, performance wise) -- The DataSource is not disposed anyway if you don't call Dispose() on it, not clear why you're saying that. It's the data source of your Control

Set the DisplayMember before the DataSource

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Disposing the Datatable dt, forces also the combobox to be deleted, which is the cause that you get a empty
Also as pointed ou you should call dispalymamber before the setting of the data source, so that the program isn't sorced to fill the datasource twice
    Dim sqliteCon As New SqliteConnection
    sqliteCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath() & "testdb.db"

    sqliteCon.Open()

    Dim sqliteCmd As SqliteCommand = sqliteCon.CreateCommand()
    Dim reader As SqliteDataReader
    '-----------------------------------
    sqliteCmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS colorsT (colorID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Color TEXT);"
    sqliteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    '-----------------------------------
    sqliteCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO colorsT (Color) VALUES ('Red'), ('Green'), ('Blue');"
    sqliteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    '-----------------------------------
    sqliteCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Color FROM colorsT ORDER BY Color;"
    reader = sqliteCmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim dT As New DataTable
    dT.Load(reader)

    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Color"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dT


    'Log(ComboBox1.Items(1).ToString) 'outputs: System.Data.DataRowView 

    'dT.Dispose()  <--- removed
    reader.Close()
    sqliteCmd.Dispose()
    sqliteCon.Close()

